# I don't like it too

Tags: grammaticality, negation, agreement, negative-polarity-items

I know that the sentence "I don't like it, either" is correct.

I've come across some native speakers say, "I don't like it,too." What about this variant?

Comment: There's a slight difference in connotation. "I don't like it, either" addresses the topic. "I don't like it, too" addresses the correspondent who "didn't like it".

Comment: Many thanks for clearing that up.